# Откуда пошла русская ИГОЛКА

Tags: этимология

Русс. **ИГОЛКА** (праслав. ***jьgъla**) имеет множество родственников в славянских языках.

В ряду прочих примеров Фасмер приводит лат. **аеgеr** "больной", а так же лтш. **îgstu**, **îgt** "чахнуть, изнывать", которые связаны с лит. **ingzdù** "жалуюсь", и польск. **jędzа** "фурия, ведьма".

Честно говоря, не очень понятно зачем он привел эти, на мой взгляд, неудачные примеры.

Ведь и без них есть более удачные:  нем. **IGEL** = ёж, **NAGEL** = гвоздь; англ. **NEEDLE** = игла, **NAIL** = гвоздь; фран. **AIGUILLE** = игла; а так же порт. **AGULHA** = игла, иголка и исп. **AGUJA** = игла, иголка.

Почему были обойдены эти родственники?

Comment: **Needle** (англ.) - игла; родственно слав. *нить* (данные OED).

Comment: Хорошие данные Оксфорда! 
К тому же, англ. CROCHET needle - крючок для вязания.
И еще странно, что CROCHET - вязать!(крючком).

Answer (score 2):

Игла - общеславянское слово jegъla, предполагаемый и.-е. корень aig-u).

Этимология слова не полностью ясна. В словаре Шанского указывается, что исходное значение слова  - это **палочка, перекладина**, которую продевают через концы хомута. Игла и иго имеют общее происхождение, иго буквально - то, что связывает, соединяет.

Сравнить:  yugam  - хомут (др.инд), jugti (лит.) запрягать. Тогда в "игле" Л - это суффикс, отнесенный к конкретному значению слова как предмета для шитья.

Answer (score 2):

Из этимологического словаря Семенова :

> ИГЛА
>   Праславянское – jьgъla.
>   Некоторые исследователи связывают происхождение слова с древнепрусским ayculo – игла. Другие предполагают, что слово образовалось от «иго» (ярмо, хомут) и считают его первоначальным значением «железный прут, которым запирается ярмо на шее животного».
>   В современном русском языке «иглой» называют «швейную принадлежность, представляющую собой заостренный металлический стержень с ушком для вдевания нити».
>   Родственным является:
>   Словенское – igla.

По своему строению слово напоминает названия других инструментов или орудий : шило, метла, зубило, тесло. Если корень - ИГО, то что он обозначает?
[image]
Что такое игла?
[image]
Естественно, приходит на ум сопоставление : иго - соЮЗ. Узы - связующие нити, иглы - связующие скрепы, стержни.

Comment: Прочитал Ваши свидетельства.
Они могут иметь место. 
Однако - связь не очевидная.
Все ваши примеры исходят из семантики - столб, жердь, балка и т.п., т.е. нечто прямое и связующее.

А вот ИГО - это в русской семантике ГНЕТ, УГНЕТЕНИЕ, ГНУТЬ.
Например, в латинском это JUGO - привязывать, связывать, JUGUM - ИГО, рабство, ярмо.

В немецком JOCH - ИГО, ярмо, гнет (переход Г-Х).
В английском YOKE - ИГО, ярмо, хомут. 
Так же и в греческом ΖΥΓΙ (ЗИГИ) - вес или ΖΥΓΟΣ (т.е. ЗИГОС) - в значении ГНЕТ, ярмо.

Comment: Ну что вы, Федор, со своим **угнетением** носитесь, как Архимед со штопором? Вы знаете, что любые слова и понятия в течение веков переосмысливаются во все возможные стороны, или вообще не в курсе. Когда первой лошади надели на шею хомут, и она радостно заржала : *иго-го!*, её хозяин ещё не знал совсем, что нечто подобное ожидает в будущем человека. Потом уже ассоциации приплыли, спустя тыщи лет. Игла - не средство для вашего угнетения, а инструмент для протыкания или скрепления чего-нибудь. *Палец* вот ещё есть для соединения деталей, вы тоже про него шум поднимать будете, или как.

Answer (score 1):

> > Почему были обойдены эти родственники?

Потому что это в лучшем случае сестры, а этимология занимается происхождением слов. То есть ищет предков.

Comment: это не сестры, а пасынки, потому как у Фасмера, вообще не этимология, а набор переводов с применением дралоскопа сильно кособокого, на немецкий лад, без этимологии самих исходных им подставляемых.

Comment: Кажется, Вы правы.
Не раз уже сталкивался со странными этимологиями Фасмера, объяснения которым не дают ни лингвисты, ни сам автор словаря.